# Verify my proof : Suppose $A\cap B\subseteq C\setminus D.$ Prove that if $x\in A,$ then if $x\in D$ then $x\notin B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm working through Velleman's book "How to Prove it", I learn alone without any help from a profession mathematician and I need some help from the community. Here is an exercise which I did, but I don't know if it is really correct:

Exercise 9 from page 100:

> Suppose $A\cap B\subseteq C\setminus D.$ Prove that if $x\in A,$ then if $x\in D$ then $x\notin B$

**Proof**. Let's prove by contradiction, suppose $x\in B$. Because $x∈A$ and $x∈B$ the relation $A\cap B$ is true. Next because $A\cap B$ implies $C\setminus D$,  $C\setminus D$ means that $x\in C$ and $x\notin D$. Here we have a contradiction, because one of the original premises says that $x\in D.$ $\blacksquare $

REMARK : I want the proof to be not too terse and not too wordy, something in the middle.

Comment: Your proof is ok

Comment: I would not write "$A\cap B$ implies $C\setminus D.$" The correct phrasing is "$x\in A\cap B$ implies $x\in C\setminus D.$" "Implies" is used between logical statements, but neither $A\cap B$ nor $C\setminus D$ is a logical statement, they are just sets.  Other than that, the proof looks fine.

Comment: The only problem I see is that $A\cap B$ and $C\setminus D$ aren't relations or statements, so $A\cap B$ cannot have a truth value and $A\cap B$ cannot imply $C\setminus D$.  If you stick in $x \in [\ldots]$ into each, it'll be fine.